# Respond with video file from local disk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, video, http-headers

I'm trying to create controllers action that responds with local video file that is outside of the applications public directory. What I have now is

```
def video
  render :text => File.read('D:/test.mp4'), :content_type => 'video/mp4'
end
```

browser recognizes that it should threat response as a video file however video content is not played appropriately. Am I missing something here? Do you know some better/other solution? Copying each file to the public directory seems to be a workaround but it also seems to be a really bad idea ). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) or [send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data) instead.